# I want to install google chrome on google colab notepad

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i have written python script on google colab but i cant install google chrome on colab notepad. I keep getting an error that it can't open chrome properly.

I need to install google chrome on google colab notepad.

these are my script in order:

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install colorama
!pip install pystyle
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

```
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from colorama import Fore
from pystyle import Center, Colors, Colorate
import os

os.system(f"title Kichi779 - Twitch Viewer Bot @kichi#0779 ")

print(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.green_to_cyan, Center.XCenter("""

# Chrome location
chrome_path = 'D:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
# The driver that has the same version as your currently installed Google chrome must be installed.
driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
service = Service(driver_path)

twitch_username = input(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.green_to_blue, ("Enter your channel name (e.g Kichi779): ")))
proxy_count = int(
    input(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.cyan_to_blue, ("How many proxy sites do you want to open? (Viewer to send)"))))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Dodaj opcję headless
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://www.blockaway.net')

text_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'url')
text_box.send_keys(f'www.twitch.tv/{twitch_username}')

text_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

for i in range(proxy_count):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.blockaway.net/')")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    text_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'url')
    text_box.send_keys(f'www.twitch.tv/{twitch_username}')
    text_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

input(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.red_to_blue, ("Viewers have all been sent. You can press enter to close it...")))
```

Comment: Why not just run `!apt install google-chrome`?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package google-chrome

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).